# How to open a new window by a link within an iframe

Tags: cordova, iframe, anchor

I am writting a cordova application, which should work for android, ios and web.

In side that app I using an iframe, where I am loading html pages (from our server, which I could manipulate if necessary).
So I am currently using the iframe like:

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-top-navigation" name="iframe" frameBorder="0" seamless="seamless" src="http://www.ourserver.com/file.html" />
```

Within these html files, I have links, which I would like to open in a new  window. I wrote a function which is handling the opening of a link, which can be reached with `window.openLink(url)` from outside the iframe.
Any idea how I can open a link from within the iframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have two possibilities:

1. the link is opened in the main app window, inside your app,
   fullscreen
2. the link is opened in the device browser, fullscreen

In both cases you should use the inAppBrowser [plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser).

It [seems](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10753), for the actual moment, you can't open the link into the iFrame.

Here is a snippet for you:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {        
        window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;
    }

$(document).on('click', 'a[href^=http], a[href^=https]', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this),
            target = $this.data('inAppBrowser') || '_system'; // system open the device browser. _blank open inappbrowser
        window.open($this.attr('href'), target, 'location=no');
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is quite outdated, but as I was facing a similar issue I am adding an answer anyway.

Our issue was that we had no control over the iframe being presented, and therefore could not do the needed overrides to make Zappescu's solution work, so instead we ended out extending Cordova to handle links which requested to be opened elsewhere than the main frame differently and instead open them though the platforms browser

Our solution currently only supports iOS using `WKWebView` but the other platforms should have similar solutions.

The main thing we did was to send our own `WKUIDelegate` instance to the WKWebView

```
[self.webViewEngine updateWithInfo:@{
    kCDVWebViewEngineWKUIDelegate : uiDelegate
}];
```

And inside that delegate we added a `createWebViewWithConfiguration` to handle these URLs

```
- (WKWebView *)webView:(WKWebView *)webView createWebViewWithConfiguration:(WKWebViewConfiguration *)configuration forNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction windowFeatures:(WKWindowFeatures *)windowFeatures {
    if (!navigationAction.targetFrame.isMainFrame) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:navigationAction.request.URL.absoluteString]];
    }
    return nil;
}
```

The actual plugin is here: https://github.com/trendsales/cordova-iframe-navigation

Hope this can serve as an entry point to others who face this issue